# Python Dictionary Assistence

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and I am using python to query a device for information.  The information that is returned is an IP address, and a score.  For example the data may look like:

```
192.168.1.1

3

192.168.1.1

4

10.10.1.1

2

10.10.1.1

3
```

The lists are very long, but using the above as a sample I am trying python to return the information above in this format.

```
192.168.1.1

7

10.10.1.1

5
```

I thought I could use a dictionary to do this.  As I get an IP address I open the dictionary and either add the IP as a new record, or it exists do nothing.  If the IP was new and was added, then it would also add the subsequent number.  If the IP was already in the dictionary, it would ADD the number to the IP.  For example, if `192.168.1.1:3` was in the dictionary, and the next value was `192.168.1.1` and `4`, the IP would not be added since the key is already in the dictionary, but the `4` would be added to the previous value of `3` and the new dictionary would entry would be: `192.168.1.1:7`

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Have you tried writing any code so far? Where specifically are you stuck? Can you show us how far you've gotten?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share any code you've written so far. You may want to read the "[ask]" section of the FAQ.

Comment: I was unaware of collections.defaultdict, and I have written some code, several times, but I write and delete and write and delete (in my frustration).  I realize now that I should have at least saved and posted some of my very simple code here.

Answer (score 6):

Use the dictionary [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method which can return a default value if the key is not found.

```
data = {}
for ip, score in your_results:
   data[ip] = data.get(ip, 0) + score
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

counts = defaultdict(int)

with open('ips') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if re.match(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', line):
            ip = line
        elif re.match(r'\d+', line):
            counts[ip] += int(line)

for k in counts:
    print(k)
    print(counts[k])
```